# How to find the following integral? $\int\tfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+3x^2}}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find: $$\int\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+3x^2}}\,\mathrm dx$$

I can't fully integrate this, I get $1/x+\sqrt3 x$ and then I don't know what to do, not sure if I even started it correctly, thanks in advance.

Comment: HINT: put $\sqrt{1+3x^2}=u$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Are you sure? I would make $u=1+3x^2$. I'm interested if yours is another way that works, though.

Comment: @EricAuld, you can choose anyone $\sqrt{1+3x^2}=u,$ or $1+3x^2=u^2$ or $1+3x^2=u$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I see it now! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check first (chain rule) that

$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{f(x)}}dx=2\sqrt{f(x)}+C$$

and now observe that

$$\frac x{\sqrt{1+3x^2}}=\frac16\frac{(1+3x^2)'}{\sqrt{1+3x^2}}$$